# $\int_{-1}^\infty e^{-x^2-2x+3}dx$ Having trouble with a specific integral and finding if it's convergent or not.

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm not sure how i'm supposed to approach this integral
$$
\int_{-1}^\infty e^{-x^2-2x+3}dx
$$
I can see that the function under the integral is positive and that it's a type I improper integral. I tried using the $\alpha$ criterium where if there is an $x^\alpha$ with $\alpha>1$ so that there is a $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x^\alpha f(x)$ the integral converges.

I thought to write it as $$e^3\lim_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha \cdot \frac{1}{e^{x^2+2x}}$$

It's clear that $\frac{1}{e^{x^2+2x}}$ becomes $0$ after the limit is applied... Is this case unidentified(meaning the integral is divergent) or am I heading the wrong path? (please excuse my english, it is not my first language)

Comment: Your approach is right. The limit is $0$(which "exists") and the integral is convergent.

Comment: How is the limit $0$ if $x^{\alpha}$ becomes $\infty$ after aplying the limit, wouldnt it be $\infty \cdot 0$ ?

Comment: You could compare $e^{-x^2-2x+3}$ with $e^{-x^2}$ by just comparing there exponents.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $-x^2-2x+3$ as $-(x+1)^2+4$;
$$\int_{-1}^\infty e^{-x^2-2x+3}\mathrm{d}x=e^4\int_{-1}^\infty e^{-(x+1)^2}\mathrm{d}x=e^4\int_{0}^\infty e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u$$
Since $e^t\geq 1+t \quad \forall t \in [0,+\infty) \implies \dfrac{1}{1+u^2}\geq \dfrac{1}{e^{u^2}}$. It follows
$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u \leq \int_{0}^\infty  \dfrac{1}{1+u^2}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
Thus the initial integral converge.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way.

You can also note that on the one hand, $e^{-x^2-2x+3}$ is positive for all real $x$, and on the other hand, the inequality $-x^2-2x+3 < -x+1$ for all $x \ge 1$. And so the inequality $|e^{-x^2-2x+3}| \le e^{-x+1}$ holds for all $x \ge 1$.

Thus, compare $\int_1^{\infty} e^{-x^2-2x+3} dx$ with $\int_1^{\infty} e^{-x+1}dx$ $=$ $e$.... In particular, we know already that $\int_1^{\infty} e^{-x+1}dx$ is convergent. **Use the fact then, that the inequality $|e^{-x^2-2x+3}| \le e^{-x+1}$ holds for all $x \ge 1$**, to conclude the inequality $$\int_1^{\infty} |e^{-x^2-2x+3}|dx \le \int_1^{\infty} e^{-x+1}dx$$ $$=e.$$
Thus, as $\int_1^{\infty}e^{-x+1}dx$ is convergent, it follows that
$\int_1^{\infty}e^{-x^2-2x+3}dx$ must also be convergent.